# pgfplots: Use cycle list in scatter plot produced from table?

Tags: pgfplots

How can I produce a scatter plot using data from a file and use the `cycle list name` option to assign a different symbol to each entry in the file?

It seems that the manual only explains how to do this if I manually add each entry of the file through an `\addplot coordinates` command. In my case, it's much more convenient to use the `\addplot table` command to import the data.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[cycle list name=mark list*]
  \addplot[only marks] table[x=x,y=y] {mwe.dat};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The data file is:

```
x y
1.0 2.0
2.0 1.0
```

The output is:

[image]

However, what I would like to get is (note the symbol at `(2.0,1.0)` is a square):

[image]

which is what is produced by the above MWE if I replace the `axis` environment by

```
\begin{axis}[cycle list name=mark list*]
  \addplot coordinates {(1.0,2.0)};
  \addplot coordinates {(2.0,1.0)};
\end{axis}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note yourself, you need to have separate plots for the marks to change. So you could loop over all entries of the table and plot one coordinate each by installing an appropriate filter,

```
x filter/.code={\unless\ifnum\coordindex=#1
  \def\pgfmathresult{}
  \fi}
```

One can find out how many rows the data has,

```
\pgfplotstableread{mwe.dat}{\Data}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\Data}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
```

to determine the length of the loop.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.dat}
x y
1.0 2.0
2.0 1.0
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{mwe.dat}{\Data}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\Data}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\begin{axis}[cycle list name=mark list*]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numrows}
  {\addplot+[only marks,
  x filter/.code={\unless\ifnum\coordindex=#1
  \def\pgfmathresult{}
  \fi}] table[x=x,y=y] {mwe.dat};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps simpler way to achieve the same result is to use `scatter/@pre marker code`. You can store the marks in your own cycle list.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.dat}
x y
1.0 2.0
2.0 1.0
3.0 0.5
4.0 1.5
5.0 2.5
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mymarklist{"*","square*","triangle*","diamond*"}
\begin{axis}[
      scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\mymark}{{\mymarklist}[Mod(\coordindex,dim(\mymarklist))]}
      \def\markopts{mark=\mymark}
      \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
      },
      scatter/@post marker code/.code={
      \endscope
      }]
  \addplot[scatter,only marks] table[x=x,y=y] {mwe.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I need and also works on my actual dataset. I'll wait with accepting the answer in case someone else comes up with a more elegant solution - as you suggested last time!